# Java Program to write all the Neon numbers from 0 to 10

Tags: java

I am trying to find the neon no.s from 0 to 10 but it is showing 9 is not a Neon no.
Please find where the program is wrong.
(A neon number is a number where the sum of digits of a square of the number is equal to the number)
*Program:*

```
class Neon
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int n,m,y=0,z=0;
        for(n=0;n<11;n++)
        {
        m=n;

        int x=m*m;
        while(x!=0)
        {
          y=x%10;
          z=z+y;

          x=x/10;
        }
        if(z==n)
        {
        System.out.println(n+" is a Neon no.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(n+" is not a Neon no.");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Output:
0 is a Neon no.
1 is a Neon no.
2 is not a Neon no.
3 is not a Neon no.
4 is not a Neon no.
5 is not a Neon no.
6 is not a Neon no.
7 is not a Neon no.
8 is not a Neon no.
**9 is not a Neon no.**
10 is not a Neon no.

Comment: *Bug:* You're not resetting `z` to 0. --- A good coding style is to not declare variables until needed, which would likely have prevented this bug from happening.

Comment: Instead of reading your program over and over trying to spot a mistake, either use a debugger or add some print statements to see what's wrong. You expect `z==n` to be `9==9` right? Is it? You expect z to be 9 because it's 8+1, right? Is it?

Comment: Think about what really happens to `z` when your `n` for loop starts its next iteration, vs. what you think happens to `z`.

Comment: The [tag:neon] tag has nothing to do with your question. There are other neons out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Neon
{
private static int findDigitSum(int num) {
    return (num == 0) ? num : num % 10 + findDigitSum(num / 10);
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int n,m,z=0;

    for(n=0; n<11; n++)
    {
      m=n;

      int x=m*m;

      z= findDigitSum(x);//It's much easier to use a separate method to calculate sum of digits 

      if(z==n)
      {
        System.out.println(n+" is a Neon no.");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println(n+" is not a Neon no.");
      }
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
0 is a Neon no.
1 is a Neon no.
2 is not a Neon no.
3 is not a Neon no.
4 is not a Neon no.
5 is not a Neon no.
6 is not a Neon no.
7 is not a Neon no.
8 is not a Neon no.
9 is a Neon no.
10 is not a Neon no.
```

Advice:
When you declare variables, always be specific (Like number for n and digitSum for z). You used one letter variables in your code, it makes other people hard to understand what your code do.